# Get all items in Archive and Recycle Bin

Tags: sitecore-api

The code I know for getting the archive is `Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["archive"]`.
I checked the method and it has `GetEntries()` but it needs to be supplied with ItemID. Is it possible to get all items in the `archive/recycle bin` thru API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead if using `GetEntries` method which accepts entry id, you can use

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ArchiveEntry> GetEntries(int pageIndex,int pageSize)
```

like

```
var archive = Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["archive"];
var archiveEntriesForItem = archive.GetEntries(0, int.MaxValue).Where(e => e.ItemId == itemId);
```

Comment: hi @marek, sorry but i don't have the itemId value.  i just want to fetch everything in archive and recyclebin. i tried Himmat's solution but it returned empty

Comment: nvm, i removed the `Where` to fetch everything. it's now `var archiveEntriesForItem = archive.GetEntries(0, int.MaxValue)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the ID you are searching returns no results, `Archive.GetEntries(ID)` even returns everything in the recycle bin.

You can try with below sample code.

```
var dbName = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var archive = Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveManager.GetArchive("recyclebin", dbName);
var archivalId = archive.GetArchivalId(itemId); //use any item id
var data = archive.GetEntries(new ID(archivalId)).Where(x => x.ItemId == itemId);
```

Comment: ok. i will try this

Comment: the data returned empty. this is the code i used `//get archived items
                var masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
                Sitecore.Data.ID se = new ID("{38579A08-F81D-4030-8CF6-C3E6FFAA2208}");
                var archive = Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveManager.GetArchive("archive", masterDb);
                var archivalId = archive.GetArchivalId(se); //use any item id
                var data = archive.GetEntries(new ID(archivalId)).Where(x => x.ItemId == se);`